# Turbolinks - Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, content-security-policy, turbolinks

I am using "Turbolinks 5.1.0".

---

**file: Gemfile**

gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5.1'

---

**file: application layout header**

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", nonce: true %>
```

---

**file: config/initializers/content_security_policy.rb**

Rails.application.config.content_security_policy_nonce_generator = -> request { SecureRandom.base64(16) }

---

**Google chrome console error**

```
VM32 application-ae291f799496478302742f713e72f20a7958b7077387b87e18ab98c51ec979c4.js:243
```

> [Report Only] Refused to execute inline script because it violates the
>   following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' https:
>   'unsafe-inline' 'nonce-UiVx2CiP0HHN9jOOSEG43g=='". Note that
>   'unsafe-inline' is ignored if either a hash or nonce value is present
>   in the source list.

```
n.assignNewBody @ VM32 application-ae291f799496478302742f713e72f20a7958b7077387b87e18ab98c51ec979c4.js:243
n.replaceBody @ VM32 application-ae291f799496478302742f713e72f20a7958b7077387b87e18ab98c51ec979c4.js:243
(anonymous) @ VM32 application-ae291f799496478302742f713e72f20a7958b7077387b87e18ab98c51ec979c4.js:243
t.renderView @ VM32 application-ae291f799496478302742f713e72f20a7958b7077387b87e18ab98c51ec979c4.js:243
n.render @ VM32 application-ae291f799496478302742f713e72f20a7958b7077387b87e18ab98c51ec979c4.js:243
t.render @ VM32 application-ae291f799496478302742f713e72f20a7958b7077387b87e18ab98c51ec979c4.js:243
e.renderSnapshot @ VM32 application-ae291f799496478302742f713e72f20a7958b7077387b87e18ab98c51ec979c4.js:243
e.render @ VM32 application-ae291f799496478302742f713e72f20a7958b7077387b87e18ab98c51ec979c4.js:243
t.render @ VM32 application-ae291f799496478302742f713e72f20a7958b7077387b87e18ab98c51ec979c4.js:243
(anonymous) @ VM32 application-ae291f799496478302742f713e72f20a7958b7077387b87e18ab98c51ec979c4.js:243
(anonymous) @ VM32 application-ae291f799496478302742f713e72f20a7958b7077387b87e18ab98c51ec979c4.js:243
```

> **To solve this problem, seems I have two solutions as listed below**

1) Use the data-turbolinks-track: reload

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", 'data-turbolinks-track': :reload, nonce: true %>
```

OR

2) Reuse the same nonce using session-store for turbolink requests, is this correct way of solving this problem?

```
Rails.application.config.content_security_policy_nonce_generator = -> request do
  # use the same csp nonce for turbolinks requests
  if request.env["HTTP_TURBOLINKS_REFERRER"].present? && request.session["mykey"].present?
    request.session["mykey"]
  else
    request.session["mykey"] = SecureRandom.base64(16)
  end
end
```

Please suggest the correct solution here!